# Getting error PDF could not generated in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-3.2, wicked-pdf

I am getting the following error while converting the HTML file to PDF using wicked_pdf gem in Rails 3.

> error:

```
Error: Failed to execute:
["C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe", "file://C:/DOCUME~1/SUBHRA~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/wicked_pdf20150526-648-17uza61.html", "C:/DOCUME~1/SUBHRA~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20150526-648-w6l9ye.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
Error: Failed loading page file://c/DOCUME~1/SUBHRA~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/wicked_pdf20150526-648-17uza61.html (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
```

Please check my below code.

> users/index.html.erb:

```
<p>
    <%= link_to "Download pdf",download_pdf_path(:format => 'pdf') %>
</p>
```

> users/download_pdf.pdf.erb:

```
<h1>Hello pdf</h1>
```

> controller/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
    def download_pdf
    respond_to do |format|
        format.pdf{ render pdf: "/users/download_pdf.pdf.erb"}
    end 
    end
end
```

> wicked_pdf.rb:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  #:wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
  #:layout => "pdf.html",
  :exe_path => 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
   #:exe_path => Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf').to_s
}
```

> Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

I installed `wkhtmltopdf` by downloading from its site and set the path in wicked_pdf.rb file.But i am getting this type of error.I am using Rails version 3.2.19 and win-xp.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try to run "WickedPdf.new" in your rails console.

Comment: @ user123 : its giving this result  #<WickedPdf:0x309a668 @exe_path="C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmlt
opdf.exe", @binary_version=#<Gem::Version "0.9.9">>

Comment: "WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('<h1>Hello There!</h1>') " Try this.

Comment: @ user123 : I run but it is throwing same type error what i have shown in this post.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'rbconfig'

if RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /linux/
  arch = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_cpu'] == 'x86_64' ? 'wkhtmltopdf_linux_x64' : 'wkhtmltopdf_linux_386'
elsif RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /darwin/
  arch = 'wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386'
else
  raise "Invalid platform. Must be running Intel-based Linux or OSX."
end

WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: "#{ENV['GEM_HOME']}/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-#{Gem.loaded_specs['wkhtmltopdf-binary'].version}/bin/#{arch}"
}
```

Add this code to config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb

and then try

```
WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('<h1>Hello There!</h1>')
```

Comment: @ user123 : I am using win-xp

Comment: Try "bundle show wkhtmltopdf" command on command prompt. If it gives you a path then copy that path and paste it in config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb

Comment: @ user123 : I added your line in wicked_pdf.rb.But i run rails c for console it is giving error as undefined local variable or method 'arch'

Comment: @ user123 : it is throwing error as Error: Failed to execute:
["C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.9.9.3", "file://C:/DOCUME~1/SUBHRA~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/wicked_pdf20150526-3672-1arfcgp.html", "C:/DOCUME~1/SUBHRA~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20150526-3672-1vuo536.pdf"]
Error: Permission denied - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.9.9.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78750/discussion-between-satya-and-user123).

Answer (score 0):

Find wicked_pdf.rb in `path/to/gem/wkhtmltopdf/bin`, on line 64 replace `file://` with `file:///` (you can read why at https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/157). If it still didn't work out rename the file `download_pdf.pdf.erb` to `download.erb`. It works fine for me :)